# Multi-region anycast for TCP and UDP

Tags: load-balancing

Is there an option or work-around to have multi-region anycast load balancing for UDP and TCP? Cloud interface suggests that these are only single region while HTTP is multi region.

Comment: It's July 6 & it looks like TCP now supports multi-region, but UDP apparently only still supports single region :( maybe it's on its way...